# .htaccess upload_max_filesize code causing 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have to upload a files which will be having size lesser than 2gb.
The Code i wrote in .htaccess as below to increase the filesize limit(I tried finding php.ini i didnt get the file so i tried to add this in .htaccess)

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M

php_value post_max_size 2000M
```

Only This code is there in .htaccess nothing else i wrote 
as soon as i upload and load my website is shows 505 error
Is there anything i should add above or below in the above mentioned code ..

Answer (score 1):

Nope, your code is right. Try the below code:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Else, try this one:

```
@ini_set( ‘upload_max_size’ , ’25MB’ );
@ini_set( ‘post_max_size’, ’27MB’);
@ini_set( ‘memory_limit’, ’30MB’ );
```

Place it in any of your main file. If not you have to make changes in `php.ini` file only.

Answer (score 0):

You have change upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini file

Comment: No i didn't found php.ini file in my directory

Comment: This file is not in your folder this file is in your server folder

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the host person its default 200M limit *its hosting side problem*... 
I cant change any settings we dont have access in my **Resseller hosting**